# Map over nested columns and left_join one nested column to another

Tags: r

I have the following code:

Which, maps over and creates a new nested column based on the min and max of the `Petal.Length`. I would like to `left_join()` or `right_join` to this newly creates nested column the values from the nested `data` column.

```
func <- function(input){
  data.frame(
    min_to_max = seq(
      from = min(input$Petal.Length),
      to = max(input$Petal.Length),
      by = 0.01
    )
  )
}

iris2 <- iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  nest() %>% 
  mutate(
    expandDF = map(data, ~ func(.x))
  ) %>% ungroup
```

My problem is here:

```
iris2 %>% 
  mutate(
    joinedData = map(expandDF, ~left_join(data, by = c("min_to_max", "Petal.Length")))
  )
```

I expect to have many `NAs`.

I want to `left_join` two nested columns.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```r
func <- function(input){
  data.frame(
    Petal.Length = seq(
      from = min(input$Petal.Length),
      to = max(input$Petal.Length),
      by = 0.01
    )
  )
}

iris2 <- 
  iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  nest() %>% 
  mutate(
    expandDF = map(data, ~ func(.x))
  ) %>%
  select(Species, expandDF) %>% 
  unnest(c(expandDF))

left_join(iris2, iris, by = c("Species", "Petal.Length"))
```